# Can I sync a Norman strobe pack with a Nikon D5100 with something that goes on the hot shoe?

Tags: lighting, nikon-d5100

I have a Nikon D5100. I am trying to use it in a studio setting with a Norman 800w strobe pack. How do I sync the light to the camera? Is there something that can go on the hot shoe at the top of the camera?

Comment: Do you mean the Norman P808m/TLC-1 Power Supply?

Comment: Did your Normal light(s) come with PocketWizard slave? Which Norman strobe are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need a [hotshoe-to-PC sync adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004RZ9MGC) on your hotshoe and a [PC to 1/4" sync cord](https://www.adorama.com/sz13562.html) (or a [cheaper generic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OXMG9O)) to run from the adapter on your hotshoe to the Norman Power Pack. The cords are available in many lengths and brand/quality levels. There are also a large number of sources for such adapters.

Check your camera's manual to find the maximum flash voltage tolerance and check the manual of your Norman Power pack to find the trigger voltage. If your camera can't tolerate the trigger voltage of the Norman Power Pack, you'll need a [hotshoe-to-PC sync adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009UU18) that also provides voltage reduction. Otherwise you could fry your camera's flash circuit or maybe even your camera's main power board.