# Can I use a Godox AD200 without a transmitter?

Tags: flash, wireless-triggers, godox

I wanted to know if I can use Godox AD 200 without the transmitter such as X1 T or Pro? The camera I would be using is Sony a7riii.

If it's a required device then why doesn't it come with the flash light itself?

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to know if I can use Godox AD 200 without the transmitter such as X1 T or Pro?

**Yes, there are several methods one may use to trigger a Godox AD200 without using a Godox 2.4Ghz transmitter.**

- You could use a wired connection between your camera's [PC terminal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45393/15871) (or [an adapter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/89714/15871) mounted on the hot shoe if your camera does not have a PC terminal) and the AD200's 3.5mm sync port.
- You could use another flash mounted on your camera's hot shoe to trigger the AD200 using a "dumb" optical slave mode. The AD200 has both [S1 and S2 slave modes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/112268/15871).
- You could shoot in an extremely dark room, use the camera in **Bulb** mode and trigger the flash manually using the AD200 control panel.
- You could use a wireless trigger system from a different manufacturer connected to the camera via a PC terminal or hot shoe, and connected to the AD200 via the wired 3.5mm sync port.

> If it's a required device then why doesn't it come with the flash light itself?

Because even if you wisely choose to use the Godox 2.4Ghz radio system, you only need one for the camera no matter how many different flashes you want it to trigger. One XPro, X1T, or X2T is all you need to control up to 16 groups in manual power mode and up to 5 groups in mixed/TTL power modes. **Why should you have to pay extra for an additional controller you don't need with every additional flash you buy?**

Answer (score 2):

> why doesn't it come with the flashlight itself?

This is in general for flash heads, not only the Godox brand.

Imagine this scenario. You want a 3 light setup for a portrait... You would end with two triggers on the shelf and one in your camera. If you need to illuminate a big building... You got the idea.

The remote trigger is not a required device. It is part of a system, but you can use a flash without the transmitter, yes.

You could use it as a slave using some other trigger systems.

- Some other models of the trigger.*
- A cable
- Another brand + a cable
- Optical slave
- Human interface... Get an assistant and put your camera on B.

---

(*)For example, in my studio I am using a different brand, but the idea is the same.

On top of my camera, I have a small trigger that is not bulky, and I carry a bigger trigger that controls the output and groups on my hand. This way I do not move the camera when changing the power of the different lights.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a  regular flash for your Sony a7R III, you can use that to trigger the AD200 using it’s built in S1/S2 optical slave mode.

Another basic method is using a Sync Cord with a 3.5mm plug.

The older FT-16 transmitter/receiver system is also compatible with the AD200.